# Is Windows blocking access to a remote MySQL server with a firewall?

Tags: mysql, r, remote-server, rmysql

I have an interesting issue connecting to a MySQL database remotely on my Windows 7 machine at work.

I'd like to connect to a **remote** MySQL database stored by hostpapa. At home on my mac, I use the following code successfully (after ensuring that my home mac IP address is an allowed user on the database side):

```
library(RMySQL)

# Connection Database SQL with RStudio
db <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                user='admin',
                password='mypassword',
                dbname='admin_dbase',
                host='mywebsite.ca')
```

It connects to the database and I'm able to view tables, etc.

In Windows - same code - no luck. Error message is:

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mywebsite.ca' (0)
```

I've attempted to add RStudio and R to the Windows Firewall as "allowed programs" and I've also gone to Windows Firewall -> advanced settings -> Inbound rules -> New Rule -> and added a TCP Port for port 3306. (I also tried adding `port = 3306,` as an argument in the dbConnect call).

Now, I know these credentials work on my mac, so it's gotta be something to do with the settings on my Windows machine. Also, the error message doesn't say there **isn't** a MySQL database, it just complains it **can't** connect.

Any ideas on how to convince my work machine to play nice?

**Note** - *I'm new to connecting to databases, so a descriptive answer would be much appreciated!**

Comment: First thing to do is make sure you can actually reach your machine at home.  There is likely a firewall issue in play, but it's likely on the end of your home machine, not your local machine (of course your corporation could be filtering traffic outbound too.. I'd have no idea if they are doing that).  I'd suggest you try to ping your home box from your Win7 box, and if that works, then look into ports.  If that does not work, you'll need to dig deeper.  Do you have a *NIX computer at work, it will have tools Win boxes don't that could help you.

Comment: I've edited my question to include that I'm new to this so I might need more descriptive help :P. My database is stored by hostpapa so that might make a difference (it's not on a local machine, it's remote).

Comment: OK, I think I'm getting the jist here.  The MySQL box is *not* at home but remote, and connecting from the MAC works OK; however you can't reach it from work; which makes me thing they might be filtering outgoing packets (not unheard of, but also I don't think very common).    There is a tool you can run from the Command prompt:   "tracert"     instructions here:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314868/how-to-use-tracert-to-troubleshoot-tcp-ip-problems-in-windows

Comment: Thanks DDeMartini... I read through the article, and used 'mywebsite.ca' as the endpoint. The first 6 hops showed IP addresses, hops 7 to 13 say that the request timed out, and hop 14 indicates that it reached hostpapa.com. Does that help determine what the problem might be!?

Comment: This means the route is OK, but what you should check is if the test over a certain port will route connect. The next tool I'd use it telnet and try to reach your host on the MySQL port (is MySQL installed / open on the normal port on that machine..   hopefully it was at least moved to a non-standard port for security reasons, but I know not all hosting companies provide that capability.     This is the next tool you want:   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx    Try:   telnet  mywebsite.ca  3306     if MySQL is on a different port, use that.

Comment: Gave that a go. telnet mywebsite.ca 3306 indicates the connection failed. How do I determine what port is correct?

Comment: Try the telnet test from your Mac at home, or contact the host provider and verify the port.  Since I didn't see the port defined in the code, I'm going to assume it's on the default port which should be 3306.

Comment: Hmm... it works from my mac so not sure that will be helpful. It does give me another port name when I try to connect using telnet **without** specifying the port, but the connection still fails.

Comment: Do you have a webserver running that remote box? If so, you could see if telnet to port 80 (or 443 for https) works..   if it does then really does sound like your IT department is not "playing nice" and is null-routing stuff on certain ports (or maybe everything other than certain ports).

Comment: I tried to move this to chat, if you're up for it! Feels like I am getting somewhere...

Comment: btw. telnet to 80 does work.

Comment: Bummer, sounds like they are filtering that port.  Not sure how you'd get around that without setting up a VPN or doing some tunneling of some sort.  Might have to talk to the IT group and see if they *are* filtering and if their policy allows them to open a route for you.